# Java iterate huge database table

Tags: java, jdbc, iteration, yield-return, large-data

I have a programme in c# that iterates a very large database query using yield return. The calling method then works on each object by calling the IEnumerable in a parallel.for each. Java does not have yield return, all the implementations I have seen for yield return in Java are very messy.

Is there another way anyone can suggest to stream rows from the dB to the calling method? So far I am thinking of putting the methods we need to run inside the SQL iterator (we use jdbc), but this also makes code review difficult as it somewhat obscures critical methods inside the reader loop.

I would provide sample code but I'm hoping for a more high level idea as this problem along with reading very large text files is common for us, c# yield return was awesome at this.

Comment: is partitioning your selects, so say only fetching 10-20% of the whole table per select, an option?

Comment: not sure if this is what you are looking for, but Spring JDBC uses a pattern where a RowMapper implementation is specified - the RowMapper has a callback method that gets called for each row in the result set, and does whatever it needs to do with it. You could use Spring JDBC, or implement this pattern yourself.

Comment: I think it would help if you provided simplified sample code. `yield return` has various uses and the best Java equivalent for each might be different. Also, could you explain how exactly did you find implementations of `yield return` “messy”?

Comment: @tttthomasssss Yes that could be an option definately. What I'd be unsure of is how to say, return a list of 10% of the table, perform an action in the calling method then resume reading the database for the next 10%. I suppose calling a row count then resubmitting the query at rowcount + 1 would work, but this again is passing more queries to and from the database.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek Thanks I will look at that, it might be the solution.

Comment: @RichardTodd it largely depends on your data of course, we did sth like that once, because we could conveniently partition the data by date (doing so for us had several benefits apart from working with smaller sets of data), if you don't have an attribute like that, i guess partitioning would then just make things messy

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/resltse5.htm

Comment: You should also see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342344(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: The ResultSet gives you access to each row similar to an Iterator.